# HowTo Generic Wildcard as Parameter

Tags: java, generics

I do have following interface.

```
interface ITest<T extends Object>{
    List<T> getValues();
    Object getValueForKey(String key, T dataObject);
}
```

so I want to use it in a static method like:

```
static createTable(ITest<?> test){
   for(? dataObject: test.getValues()){
       Object value = test.getValueForKey("KEY", dataObject)
   }
}
```

Which brings up the error: "Wildcards may be used only as reference parameters"

and of course it's not accepting an object in "getValueForKey()"

When I use this like:

```
ITest<Option> testImpl = new ITest<Option>(){
     @Override
     List<Option> getValues(){
          new ArrayList<>(10);
     }
     ...
} 

createTable(testImpl);
```

How can I achieve to stay specific in my specific interface implementation but not in the static method using the interface (Best case:without warnings of unchecked parsing/cast)

Comment: I don't get the question. The ? wildcard means "I dont care about the type". In other words: "I know nada zip niente about the type". I dont get why you want to "align" this non-knowledge with "I have a specific known type T".

Comment: What do you expect `? dataObject` to do?

Comment: It's quite simple the static method will be used with a lot of different types, and do not want to implement it type specific each time because it's quite a lot of code which would be redundant

Comment: I would expect something like for(T dataObject) or something like that because I dont care about the type

Comment: But I cannot make the static method like creatTable(ITest<Object> data)

Comment: That would result in compile error on the last lines of code

Comment: Declare ITest<T> as parameter?

Comment: Why are you using `T extends Object` if you return always a `Object`?

Comment: It's already answered no need to ask for further Information

Comment: Of course is 'data' == 'test'. I changed it.... You are now able to understand not only by the methods called on the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

```
static <T> void createTable(ITest<T> test) {
    for (T dataObject : test.getValues()) {
       Object value = data.getValueForKey("KEY", dataObject);
    }
}
```

When you use `ITest<?> test` you just declare that your parameter can be of any type you can't use `?` as `dataObject` type later. When you declare a generic method you can use `T` as a type. It's going to be inferred at compile time and because you call it with `ITest<Option> testImpl` `T` is going to be `Option`.

You also shouldn't do `<T extends Object>` it's a completely useless bound and is equivalent to just `<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass {
    static class ITest<T> {
        T[] getValues() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    static <T extends Object> void createTable(ITest<T> test) {
        for(T dataObject : test.getValues()) {
           T value = dataObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot resolve symbol T EDIT: nice no compile error. btw I did not downvote ;-)

Comment: You are doing something wrong, the following code compiles and runs